# How could I select a range of characters up until a third / is present and select all if there is no third / using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I need to select a range within a string up until the third `/` is present.

I currently have `^([^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/` but this will only work when there is more than 3 `/` in the string. Ideally I'd need to select all characters up until a third `/`, and select all if there is no third `/`

If anyone can think of a way around this that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: You may use this regex: `^([^/]*/){0,3}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match substring starting from 3rd occurrence of `/` where there may be less than 3 `/`s you may use this regex using range quantifier:

```
^(?:[^/]*/){0,3}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v5TVCU/1)

**How it works:**

- `^` We start at beginning of a line
- We are using a greedy quantifier `{0,3}` to match preceding group 0 to 3 times
- Inside the group we are matching 0 or more of any characters that are not `/` followed by a `/`

Comment: Great, thanks for that! What would I do in the case where there is a string with less than 3 / but doesn't end with a /. Using your given examples, something like start/foo would only select up to start/ and not include foo. Thanks!

Comment: For that use: `^(?:[^/\n]*/?){0,3}`

Answer (score 0):

Easy, but a little inefficient way to do it is:

```
        String input = "your/input/should/be/there";
        String[] parts = input.split("/");
        if (parts.length > 2) {
            return String.join("/", parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
        } else {
            return input;
        }
```